# Combining the distribution of the difficulty of a question with the probability of a correct answer

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I came across this question:

*Three contestants are each given the same question. They answer independently of each other. The probability of the answer being correct is $p$. The difficulty of the question is a random variable $\sim \operatorname{UNIF} (0,1]$*

Before answering the questions, I introduce a few random variables:

$X$ is the difficulty of the question: $X \sim \operatorname{UNIF} (0, 1]$

$Y$ is the number of correct answers: $Y \sim \operatorname{BIN} (3, p)$

Intuitively, I suppose $p$ depends on $X$. The actual dependence is not specified, but I assume it follows some kind of inverse relationship to $X$, as a lower difficulty will produce a higher probability of a correct answer. This means that for a given $X = x$, it follows that $p \not = x$.

I thought that a possible function that could relate $p$ to $x$ is $p = 1-x$, because at minimum difficulty $x = 0$ the probability that the answer is right should be at its maximum, $p = 1$, and at maximum difficulty $x = 1$, the probability that the answer is right should be at its minimum, $p = 0$. However, the question does not provide this.

The questions are the following:

*(a) Find $\operatorname{P} (Y = 2)$.*

So if $Y \sim \operatorname{BIN} (3, p)$, then

$$\operatorname{P}(Y = 2) = \binom{3}{2} p^2(1-p) = 3p^2 - 3p^3$$

For a general function $p = g(x)$:

$$\operatorname{P}(Y = 2) = \cdots = 3p^2 - 3p^3 = 3(g(x))^2 - 3(g(x))^3$$

I use the Law of Total Probability:

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{P}(Y = 2) & = \operatorname{E}( \operatorname{P} (Y = 2 \vert X = x)) \\
& = \operatorname{E}(3(g(x))^2 - 3(g(x))^3) \\
& = 3\operatorname{E}((g(x))^2) - 3\operatorname{E}((g(x))^3) \\
& = 3 \int_0^1 (g(x))^2 dx - 3 \int_0^1 (g(x))^3 dx
\end{align}$$

Since I don't know $g(x)$ I can't really compute a value for $\operatorname{P}(Y=2)$. For $p = 1-x$, I get $\operatorname{P}(Y=2) = \frac{1}{4}$

*(b)Find $\operatorname{E} (Y)$.*

So, again, $Y \sim \operatorname{BIN} (3, p)$. Then:

$$\operatorname{E}(Y) = np = 3p$$

Again, for a general function $p = g(x)$ I use the Law of Total Expectation:

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}(Y) & = \operatorname{E}(\operatorname{E}(Y \vert X = x)) \\
& = \operatorname{E}(3g(x)) \\
& = 3 \operatorname{E}(g(x))\\
& = 3 \int_0^1 g(x) dx \\
& = 3(G(1) - G(0))\\
\end{align}$$

Again, I can't really derive a numerical value for $\operatorname{E}(Y)$ because I don't know $g(x)$ or $G(x)$ (note that $\frac{d(G(x))}{dx} = g(x)$).

If I use $p = 1-x$, I get $\operatorname{E}(Y) = \frac{3}{2}$

I want to think that the question is vague and that I need $g(x)$ to be able to solve it, but maybe there's another way to derive $\operatorname{P}(Y=2)$ and $\operatorname{E}(Y)$.

Is there?

Comment: I did not check your math in detail, but based on the wording of the question I would also assume $p = 1-X$ (or more relevantly, $p \sim U(0,1]$).  After all, what is $p$ but the a parameter of how "difficult" the question is?

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly my thought process. However, I think that the questions would've been more clear if it explicitly stated that $p = 1 - X$, because as it stands now, the relationship could be anything.

Comment: Yes I agree, but IMHO this is a rather minor, totally forgiveable lapse.  :)  Interestingly, if the wording had been "the EASINESS of the question is a r.v. $\sim U(0,1]$" would you have been less confused because you'd be more ready to associate $p$ with EASINESS than with DIFFICULTY?